# Kafka Streams on Confluent Cloud: 'segment.ms' with value '600000' exceeded min limit of 14400000 for internal repartition topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Running on Confluent Cloud with kafka streams version 2.1.0
Getting the following error when kafka streams app starts:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Config property 'segment.ms' with value '600000' exceeded min limit of 14400000.
```

full call stack:

```
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.prepareTopic(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:967)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:525)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:403)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:569)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:95)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:521)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:504)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:870)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:850)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:575)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:389)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:397)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:340)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:341)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1214)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1179)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:913)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:818)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

The invalid value is coming from RepartitionTopicConfig

```
 private static final Map<String, String> REPARTITION_TOPIC_DEFAULT_OVERRIDES;
    static {
        final Map<String, String> tempTopicDefaultOverrides = new HashMap<>();
        tempTopicDefaultOverrides.put(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_DELETE);
        tempTopicDefaultOverrides.put(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_INDEX_BYTES_CONFIG, "52428800");               // 50 MB
        tempTopicDefaultOverrides.put(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_BYTES_CONFIG, "52428800");                     // 50 MB
        tempTopicDefaultOverrides.put(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG, "600000");                          // 10 min
        tempTopicDefaultOverrides.put(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));  // Infinity
        REPARTITION_TOPIC_DEFAULT_OVERRIDES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempTopicDefaultOverrides);
    }
```

Comment: From Kafka documentation I found that `segment.ms` is `This configuration controls the period of time after which Kafka will force the log to roll even if the segment file isn't full to ensure that retention can delete or compact old data.`. Only default value on Confluent page that has `14400000` was `confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.roll.ms` which means `Log rolling time for the metrics topic`. It could be that Confluent Metrics Reporter has its own topic settings, that are conflicting with those default ones from RepartitionTopicConfig.

Comment: Eventually fixed by adding 
StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG) -> "14400000"
to the StreamsConfig

Comment: You should put a proper answer for your own question (and accept it).

Comment: Btw: we are aware of this issue, and plan to lift this restriction so changing the `segment.ms` config in Streams won't be necessary any longer. We might even consider to change the default in KS -- 10 minutes seems to be rather low -- but that's a AK community decision.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually fixed by adding `StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG) -> "14400000"` to the StreamsConfig

Comment: Btw: we are aware of this issue, and plan to lift this restriction so changing the `segment.ms` config in Streams won't be necessary any longer. We might even consider to change the default in KS -- 10 minutes seems to be rather low -- but that's a AK community decision.